# Address case class by field

Tags: scala

I have a module which simulates the game of chess, with the following two classes:

```
case class Pos(x: Char, y: Char)
abstract class Piece(player: Int, pos: Pos)
```

I have a set of `Piece`:

```
val pieces: Set[Piece]
```

I would like to filter it like this:

```
pieces.filter(piece => !(piece.pos == pos2))
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error:(45, 36) value pos is not a member of chess.Piece
    pieces.filter(piece => !(piece.pos == pos2))
                               ^
```

Why is this the case? Can I not reference a variable of type `Piece` with `.pos`?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of the abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because there are no getters set up for your Piece class.

```
// No getters/setters created
abstract class Piece(player: Int, pos: Pos) 

// Only Getters created because constructor params are immutable 
abstract class Piece(val player: Int, val pos: Pos) 

// Both Getters & Setter created because constructor params are mutable 
abstract class Piece(var player: Int, var pos: Pos)
```